# Cannot create new Android Application Project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

So, I'm trying to start a new Android project, but I can't get through the first step.
Everything looks good to me, but the 'Next' button just won't light up for me.

Of note, the 'Theme' menu starts off on 'Holo Light with Dark Action Bar' and a red X next to it. This will stay red after changing it (even to 'none') unless it's the first thing I do when I get to this form. Seems weird. Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

There is nothing listed in 'Compile With', but I do have SDK Platforms installed and up to date.

[image: Can't complete Android project creation]

Comment: I use a Maven archetype for creating project instead of the eclipse project, but if I start the same window, in Compile With list I have all downloaded SDK..

you should check your SDK location in Eclipse preferences

Comment: Interesting. When I go to check the SDK location, I get this error on top:

"This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 21.1.0 or above.  Current version is 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58.  Please update ADT to the latest version."

But when I try to update, it says there are no updates.

Comment: Have you tried going to Help-> Check for software Updates?

Comment: Yeah, it says there are none. Which is obviously wrong. I should probably just try to reinstall.

Comment: Are you using Android SDK Manager for checking updates ? 

On the top of the packages list, I have a folder "Tools" with Android SDK Tools to the rev. 21.1.

Comment: Oh wait a minute. I have that too, "21.1 - INSTALLED", but the error says I have 21.0.

Comment: Think I should delete the 21.1 Tools package and reinstall that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trashing my adt directory and re-downloading the bundle from Google in order to get it to properly "update" to 21.1.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the any sdk platform is not installed on your computer thats why the compile with field is empty and next button is not shown so first installed any one of the SDK platform.
Launch Android SDK manager and installed any SDK platform.